# Python removing multiple lines beginning using a list of strings

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to remove multiple lines from a file where the lines begin with a specified string.
I've tried using a list as below but the lines are written to the file the number of times equal to the items in the list. Some of the lines are removed some are not I'm pretty sure that it is due to not reading the next line at the correct time

```
    trunklog = open('TrunkCleanedDaily.csv', 'r')
fh = open("TCDailyFinal.csv", "w")
firstletter = ['Queue,Completed', 'Outbound,', 'Red_Team_DM,', 'Sunshine,', 'Agent,','Disposition,', 'Unknown,']
 
while True:
    line = trunklog.readline()
    if not line:
        break;
    for i in firstletter:
        if line.startswith(i):
            print('del ' + line, end='')
            # line = trunklog.readline()
        else:
            fh.write(line)
            print('keep ' + line,end='')
            line = trunklog.readline()
```

Any help setting me straight about this is appreciated.

Some of the content I am trying to remove:

```
Queue,Completed,Abandons,Exits,Unique,Completed %,Not Completed %,Total Calls,
Green_Team_AMOne,93,0,0,0,100.00%,0.00%,8.04%,
Green_Team_DM,11,0,0,0,100.00%,0.00%,0.95%,
Green_Team_IVR,19,0,0,0,100.00%,0.00%,1.64%,
Outbound,846,131,0,0,86.59%,13.41%,84.44%,
Red_Team_AMOne,45,0,0,0,100.00%,0.00%,3.89%,
Red_Team_DM,3,0,0,0,100.00%,0.00%,0.26%,
Red_Team_IVR,5,0,0,0,100.00%,0.00%,0.43%,
Sunshine,4,0,0,0,100.00%,0.00%,0.35%,
Queue,Total Call Time,Average Call Time,Average Hold Time,Call Time %,None,
Green_Team_AMOne,32:29:06,20:57,00:10,42.92%,None,
Green_Team_DM,2:41:35,14:41,00:16,3.56%,None,
Green_Team_IVR,1:47:12,05:38,00:19,2.36%,None,
```

Comment: While handling csv, i would suggest using a library ```csv``` or ```pandas``` only because there are higher chances of errors if you miss one separator and manipulating csv data can be easier. also could you upload the file content and what you want to remove

Comment: You're skipping lines. Remove the last line in the code: `line = trunklog.readline()`.

Comment: If I comment out the last line then I get 6 to 7 copies of each line in the output file. 6 when one matches the list item 7 when nothing matches.

Comment: Yash, are you suggesting that I use csv or pandas for removing the lines I do not want?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
trunklog = open('TrunkCleanedDaily.csv', 'r')
fh = open("TCDailyFinal.csv", "w")
firstletter = ['Queue,Completed', 'Outbound,', 'Red_Team_DM,', 'Sunshine,', 'Agent,', 'Disposition,', 'Unknown,']

for line in trunklog:
    cnt=0
    for i in firstletter:
        if line.startswith(i):
            print('del ' + line, end='')
            cnt=1

    if not cnt:
        fh.write(line)
        print('keep ' + line, end='')
```

I have modified your code a little bit.
And added a variable 'cnt', which will be 1, if first word is in firstletter list.
If cnt=0, then it will write line to the new file.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to left intend else statement for `for` loop and add `break` if you have to delete a line.

```py
trunklog = open('TrunkCleanedDaily.csv', 'r')
fh = open("TCDailyFinal.csv", "w")
firstletter = ['Queue,Completed', 'Outbound,', 'Red_Team_DM,', 'Sunshine,', 'Agent,','Disposition,', 'Unknown,']
 
while True:
    line = trunklog.readline()
    if not line:
        break;
    for i in firstletter:
        if line.startswith(i):
            print('del ' + line, end='')
            break
    else:
        fh.write(line)
        print('keep ' + line,end='')
```

**Output file**

```
Green_Team_AMOne,93,0,0,0,100.00%,0.00%,8.04%,
Green_Team_DM,11,0,0,0,100.00%,0.00%,0.95%,
Green_Team_IVR,19,0,0,0,100.00%,0.00%,1.64%,
Red_Team_AMOne,45,0,0,0,100.00%,0.00%,3.89%,
Red_Team_IVR,5,0,0,0,100.00%,0.00%,0.43%,
Queue,Total Call Time,Average Call Time,Average Hold Time,Call Time %,None,
Green_Team_AMOne,32:29:06,20:57,00:10,42.92%,None,
Green_Team_DM,2:41:35,14:41,00:16,3.56%,None,
Green_Team_IVR,1:47:12,05:38,00:19,2.36%,None,
```